# Override service implementation inside DI scope

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, service-provider

How do I register a different service implementation within a scope using miscrosoft's default DI mechanism?

My case is this:

I have a service (let's call it MyJobService) that depends on context values (logged in user and some other information). I have registered another service (UserSessionProvider) that reads the data needed from the current HttpContext. But my initial service may also run in a background job, where HttpContext does not exist, **but** the job is fired from within a web request.

So I would like to have a second implementation of UserSessionProvider where the information of current user is not read from the http context but it would be passed as readonly data to the service implementation and then I would use this instance of UserSessionProvider as the implementation within the created scope.

```
public IActionResult ControllerMethod(
   [FromService] IUserSessionProvider sessionProvider, // this instance reads from http context
   [FromServices] IServiceProvider sp)
{
    var staticSessionProvider = new StaticDataSessionProvider(  // this instance uses what you pass to the constructor
      userName: sessionProvider.userName,
      userData: sessionProvider.userData
    );
    
    ExecuteInBackground(()=>{
     using(var scope = sp.CreateScope()){
       scope.AddScoped<IUserSessionProvider>(staticSessionProvider); // can I do that?
       var myJob=scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyJobService>(); // here 'myJob' would use the staticDataSessionProvider instance
       myJob.Run();
     }
    });
      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I register a different service implementation within a scope using miscrosoft's default DI mechanism?

You can't. At the end of the startup process, the container is created, and its set of registrations is fixed. This is a good thing, because allowing to change the container midway can lead to very unfortunate consequences (as is discussed in [this documentation section](https://simpleinjector.org/locked) of this competing DI Container). You'll have to come up with another solution.

For instance, you can create a proxy implementation and use that as a stand in:

```cs
// Proxy implementation that dispatches to the real IUserSessionProvider
public sealed class OverwritableUserSessionProvider : IUserSessionProvider
{
    // NOTE: Depends on the UserSessionProvider implementation
    public OverwritableUserSessionProvider(UserSessionProvider provider)
    {
        this.Provider = provider;
    }
    
    // Allows replacing the dependency
    public IUserSessionProvider Provider { get; set; }
    
    // Implement IUserSessionProvider
    public string UserName => this.Provider.UserName;
    public UserData UserData => this.Provider.UserData;
}
```

This proxy and the real provider can be registered as follows:

```cs
// Register both the 'real' provider and the proxy.
services.AddScoped<UserSessionProvider>();
services.AddScoped<OverwritableUserSessionProvider>();

// Register the proxy as IUserSessionProvider.
services.AddScoped<IUserSessionProvider>(
    sp => sp.GetRequiredService<OverwritableUserSessionProvider>());
```

This allows you to implement your `ControllerMethod` as follows:

```cs
var staticSessionProvider = new StaticDataSessionProvider(
  userName: sessionProvider.userName,
  userData: sessionProvider.userData);

ExecuteInBackground(() =>
{
    using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
    {
        // Resolve the proxy
        var provider = scope.ServiceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<OverwritableUserSessionProvider>();
            
        // Replace the default dependency
        provider.Provider = staticSessionProvider;
        
        // Resolve and execute the service as usual.
        var myJob = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyJobService>(); 
        myJob.Run();
    }
});
```

> **TIP:** Extract this logic out of the controller and into a specialized class; this logic is infrastructure and has a different concern compared to the controller.

There are other solutions and variations possible based on the solution above, but the trick here is to always ensure that the container composes the same object graph. Don't make the composed object structure dynamic; [don't base it on runtime data](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/).

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much how I imagined it should be implemented if DI did not support that scenario. I will try it and come back!

Comment: I understand that it is better to lock the registrations before first use, but wouldn't be more convenient, just for scoped services, to be able to overwrite registration when a new scope is created? I mean: create scope->override registrations->lock registrations within thar scope. If you need another override, create another nested scope. And all this, just for the scoped services.

Comment: Even if a hypothetical library would allow that, there would still be many caveats. It effectively disables optimization of object graph composition, because services need to be replaced. And there are design issues; what if you replace an instance from a scope that already has been used to resolve instances? You get into the same Captive Dependency issue as would happen with singletons (but within a single scope). And from an API perspective it becomes confusing to a user that some services can be replaces (the scoped registrations) and others can't. And would you allow replacing transients?

Comment: Thanks, I'll close my question as a dupe. Perhaps it's obvious, but still worth emphasizing that this only works for scoped services, doing it on a singleton would be a bad idea. :)

Comment: FYI Autofac allows precisely this feature. Take a dependency on `ILifetimeScope`. Call `BeginScope` and pass in a delegate which allows further registrations just for that scope. This is immensely useful for situations where a new scope is needed with a different dependency.