# Register or swap a service inside a ServiceProvider scope

Tags: asp.net-core, session, dependency-injection, httpcontext, service-provider

I am trying to find a way to swap a certain service inside a ServiceProvider scope.

The actual problem that I am trying to solve is that we have a legacy app where current user is registered as a service, and returned from the current `HttpContext`, similar to:

```
services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserInfo>(sp =>
{
    // simplified version, actually there is some HttpContext.Session caching,
    // but the idea is that we're using HttpContext to get the current user
    
    var context = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    return new CurrentUserInfo(context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
});
```

Now the issue with this is that if I want to run some background tasks after startup init, all the services that have `ICurrentUserInfo` will fail because there is no `HttpContext.Current`. So I was hoping that I could do something like:

```
using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    scope.ServiceProvider.Register<ICurrentUserInfo>(sp => /* get the "service" account */);
    
    // Resolving the services inside this scope will now work,
    // other services can still run and will use the original ICurrentUserInfo service
}
```

However I believe once the `ServiceProvider` is built from the service collection, it cannot be updated anymore.

Is there another way how this issue could be solved?

**(Update)** Found an existing answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74024822/1488067) so closing this as a dupe.

Summary of the proposed solution would be to have a proxy class registered as a scoped service, and then inside the new scope we first manually resolve the proxy and swap the implementation before doing actual work. This way the change is transparent to callers and confined to the new scope.

Comment: I believe this question to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74024502/override-service-implementation-inside-di-scope) question.

Comment: FYI Autofac has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#httpcontext-access-from-a-background-thread):

**HttpContext isn't thread-safe. Reading or writing properties of the HttpContext outside of processing a request can result in a NullReferenceException.**

you have to move your codes into the processing of  httprequest(middleware/controller/filer....) instead of change the lifetime of the service

Comment: Hi thanks, but the point is not that it's being accessed from outside a request, `ICurrentUserInfo` is injected in services used from controllers so it's never null. The HttpRequest is not even relevant, the point is that I want to provide a different implementation of `ICurrentUserInfo` in a separate scope