# How to register service dependency of an external assembly file in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, service-provider

I'm working with a ASP.NET Core 6 API project. I'm trying to implement a task scheduler.

The solution has different components like:

- API project
- Memory Queue (CL)
- Worker Service
- Task Service (CL)
- Common Service (CL, used by API and TaskService)

  ```
  API > Queue > Worker Service > Task Service > Common Service
  ```

Request first comes to the API, it saves a record to the DB and passes the id and task-type (fully qualified assembly name) to the memory queue. Worker service keep checking the queue **in background**, if there is any record, it will fetch it, and load the assembly by fully qualified name, and then execute the specific method of a Task service.

To perform some operation, task service calls common service. And the common service uses claims from `Httpcontext` when request comes from API. But when task service calls common service, it doesn't have `Httpcontext`.

Worker service:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{    
    var processingTasks = new List<Task>();

    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var tasksToProcess = new List<TaskJobModel>();

        // Dequeue a batch of tasks to process
        while (_taskQueue.TryDequeue(out var task))
        {
            if (task != null)
                tasksToProcess.Add(task);
        }

        if (tasksToProcess.Count > 0)
        {
            // Process tasks in parallel
            foreach (var task in tasksToProcess)
            {
                var processingTask = ProcessTaskAsync(task);
                processingTasks.Add(processingTask);
            }

            // Wait for all tasks to complete
            await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);

            // Clear the list of processing tasks
            processingTasks.Clear();
        }

        // Delay before the next iteration
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), stoppingToken);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
}

private Task ProcessTaskAsync(TaskJobModel taskJobModel)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(taskJobModel.JobType))
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        Assembly.Load(taskJobModel.JobType);

        var type = Type.GetType(taskJobModel.JobType) ??
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                    .Select(a => a.GetType(taskJobModel.JobType))
                    .FirstOrDefault(t => t != null);

        if (type == null)
            throw new Exception($"({taskJobModel.JobType}) cannot by instantiated");

        object? instance = GetInstance(type);

        if (instance is not IWorkerService task)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        //execute method from the specific type
        task.ExecuteAsync(taskJobModel.Id);                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error processing task {taskId}", taskJobModel.Id);
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private object GetInstance(Type type)
{    
    
    foreach (var constructor in type.GetConstructors())
    {
        var parameters = constructor.GetParameters().Select(parameter =>
        {
            var service = _serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(parameter.ParameterType);
            if (service == null)
                throw new Exception("Unknown dependency");

            return service;
        });                    

        //create an instance
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameters.ToArray()) ?? new { };
    }    
}
```

**Problem statement**

This works fine till now. However, `Taskservice` depends on some common services to perform some operation. But I could not find a way to register its dependencies.

I tried to register it into worker service startup.

```
.ConfigureServices(services =>
    services.AddScoped<IConfigSetter, CustomServerConfig>();
    services.AddScoped<IServerConfig, CustomServerConfig>(); 
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
...
```

But it appears unregistered in the `TaskService`.

TaskService.cs

```
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

public TaskService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{    
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;            
}

public async Task ExecuteAsync(Guid taskId)
{
    var config = _serviceProvider.GetService<IConfigSetter>();  
}
```

**Limitation**

This cannot be registered under API startup, as I wanted to use `CustomServerConfig` instead of the actual one which is used by API project.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dependency to the service provider is a bad practice in Object oriented programming. Instead of actual dependency to a service, your code is free to resolve **any** dependency on its own.

But take a look at your code

```
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

public TaskService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{    
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;            
}

public async Task ExecuteAsync(Guid taskId)
{
    var config = _serviceProvider.GetService<IConfigSetter>();  
}
```

What you do here is you have a dependency to a service provider (bad) but then you use the service provider to resolve the `IConfigSetter`.

Refactor it then to

```
private readonly IConfigSetter _configSetter;

public TaskService(IConfigSetter configSetter)
{    
    _configSetter = configSetter;
}

public async Task ExecuteAsync(Guid taskId)
{
    // not needded anymore, configSetter is already here
    // var config = _serviceProvider.GetService<IConfigSetter>();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it that before, it is showing an error _"No service for type 'IConfigSetter' has been registered."_ while creating an instance. And this is the issue, I'm looking for a way to register `IConfigSetter'`

Comment: That's obvious, you need to register an implementation. That's how the service provider works (e.g. `services.AddScoped<IConfigSetter, YourImplementation>()`. What you have shown in your question is registration of some `IServerConfigSetter` which is definitely different from `IConfigSetter`.

Comment: Of course! but the scenario is different here. Common services require user claims, when request route through worker service > task service > common service, I have to manually set those claims.  `IConfigSetter` has methods to set those claims. So, I want to register it only for `TaskService` and not for API. Registering it in API breaks the API request flow.

Comment: I believe the specific scenario is irrelevant. You need to register a service so that the service provider can resolve it. If your service should be used only in specific use-case, just create an extra interface, extra implementation and register the two.

Comment: My issue is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74024502/4753489), however I'm not sure how to implement it this case.

Comment: Have two separate interfaces, an easiest approach that doesn't hack or misuse the idea of a statically configured service provider